# Sequelize: Query by custom fields on a many to many relationship table between the same model

Tags: node.js, database, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have a user model with a many to many relationship with itself defined as follows. It uses a friends table as the joining table with a couple of custom fields defined on it - approved and denied.

```
const User = db.define('user', {
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    }
})

const Friend = db.define('friend', {
    approved: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    denied: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
})

User.belongsToMany(User, {through: Friend, as: 'friends'})
```

I am able to query the User table for a username and am able to get the friends list for a matched user just fine using the following:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
        username
    },
    include: {
        model: User,
        as: 'friends'
    }
})
```

However, I'm wondering how to query using the two additional fields defined on the friends' table - i.e. approved or denied. Alternatively, I have tried the following:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
        username
    },
    include: {
        model: User,
        where: {
            approved: true
        },
        as: 'friends'
    }
})
```

But this results in the error - **column friends.approved does not exist**.